# Sending client's document to me

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I'm writing telegram-bot using Telebot. Let's some person sends some document to bot (for example, .docx or .pdf file). How may I do, that after it bot will send this document to chat with me?

I tried to do something like

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["document"])
def send_order(message):
    bot.send_document(<mi_id>, message)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync_version/index.html#telebot.TeleBot.send_document), `bot.send_document` has an argument `document`, which expects a `file_id` of already existent document from Telegram servers.

To get this `file_id` you can check the [attribute](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#telebot.types.Message) `document` of `message` and get its [id](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#telebot.types.Document):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["document"])
def send_order(message):
    bot.send_document(<mi_id>, document=message.document.file_id)
```